# Prove $(P\to (Q \to R)) \to (Q \to (P \to R))$ (derivation)...

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

The problem is as stated in the title. With this problem and I am restricted to modus tollens (MT), modus ponens (MP), repetition (R), and double negation (DN). I'm just getting used to logic derivation, so I've really no idea where to proceed. The issue I'm having is just not knowing how to properly start this. This is all I've got, and I think it's the wrong direction:

> 1. Show $(P\to (Q \to R)) \to (Q \to (P \to R))$
>
>    2. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$  $P\to (Q \to R)$ $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ Assume CD
>    3. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ Show $Q\to R$
>    4. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\neg(Q\to R)$ $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$Assume ID
>    5. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\neg P$ $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ 2,4 MT

Anyone able to give me a hand? I don't need a full answer, just a step in the right direction.

Comment: What is the 'repetition'? I try to find the meaning of this word but I can't find it. Can you explain it?

Comment: Repetition isn't really necessary in these proofs, but let's say we wanted to repeat line 5 at line 8 or something. Then we'd have

"8. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\neg P$ $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ $5\;R$"

Comment: If your logic system have deduction theorem (or, $\to$-introduction rule), then the proof of it is easy. But I do not certain that I can use such rules.

Comment: I can only use $\to$,$\neg$ right now.

Comment: Anyway, which sentences are tautologies? Does your system have no tautologies?

Comment: Just checked. I don't think there exists any tautologies :X

Comment: In the title you said **with** *Natural Deduction*; if not, what set of rules are you allowed to use ?

Comment: I think I may have been confused with terminology. We're doing a logic derivation (direct derivations, conditional derivations, indirect derivations). I believe it's nested into natural deduction, but I feel my usage may have been too vague.

Comment: @user30625 - Ok, thanks; thus the aswer below is what you need; you have to assume : 1) $(P→(Q→R))$, 2) $Q$, 3) $P$; then you derive $R$ by two applications of *modus ponens* and conclude with : $ (P→(Q→R))→(Q→(P→R))$ by three applications of *conditional derivation*.

Comment: Hint: p -> q $\equiv$ ~p or q

What I sometimes to do is to convert implications as such and then use the hell out of de morgan's laws. probably inelegant though.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $P\to (Q\to R)$. (1)

We want to show $Q\to (P\to R)$.

Well, suppose $Q$. (2)

We want to show $P\to R$.

Suppose $P$. (3)

Then $Q\to R$ by 1 and 3. (4)

Then $R$ by 4 and 2.

Comment: At the risk of mentioning something you already might know, if (p→(q→p)) and ((p→(q→r))→((p→q)→(p→r))) are axioms, the above hint enables you to see that Frege's *first* axiomization of propositional calculus is not independent.

Answer (score 2):

you are correct in line 3 you go in the wrong direction:

Start with :

1 | Show $ (P \to (Q \to R)) \to (Q \to (P \to R))$

2 || $ (P \to (Q \to R)) $  Assume CD

3 || Show $ (Q \to (P \to R))$

4 ||| $ Q $  Assume CD

5 ||| Show $ P \to R $

and the rest you can do yourself (just a lot of MP)

GOOD LUCK